# Cannot /GET - What's wrong with this Express Server?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating a basic app to learn Express, but can't seem to set it up right. When I run the app I get a `Cannot /GET` error. The basic outline is something like this:

In the top directory -

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var getWx = require('./incoming/getWx.js');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1983);
app.use('/getWx', getWx);

app.listen(1983);
```

Then, in `/incoming/getWx.js`, I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
  .get(function(request, response) {
    // do thing here 
  })


module.exports = router;
```

Anything stand out here as wrong? Trying to do this with a `router` as my app will end up with multiple files.

Comment: The route you've defined should respond to a request for `/getWx/` on whatever port your server is running on.  Is that the URL you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you probably trying to access the path `/` ...

Which don't have any router set to handle it...

The router you set up handles the path `/getWx`

If you set stomething like this:

app.use('/', getWx);

The accessing path `/` will return something...

Comment: Ah. Yes. I changed `app.use('/getWx', getWx)` to `app.use('/', getWx)` and it works.